# error "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" could not be opened. Line 126: PCDATA invalid Char value 3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

Has anyone had this error or know how to fix it?

"MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" could not be opened. Line 126: PCDATA invalid Char value 3

I have no idea what it means and cannot get back to the place before this started happening.

Comment: I just remade the storyboard and works fine now. I dont know what caused it though

Comment: I had a similar error time ago and didn't know what was the cause. The storyboard is just an xml file, opening it as source file and changing wrong value by hand resolved the issue, and allowed me to reopen it as interface builder file.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue before when copying and pasting words / characters from Illustrator into a UILabel or UITextView via Interface Builder. My own conclusion is that some of the characters being used were not being escaped / encoded properly during the copy & paste operation, causing issues with the storyboard source file.